# Is there a way to parse strings better?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing

I'm wondering if there's a built in way in .NET to parse bits of a string.

Take for example I have the following string:

```
"bsarbirthd0692"
```

made up of the following parts that will be cross referenced to data later:

```
Indexes   Purpose
0-3       (name)
4-9       (description)
10-13     (date mm-yy)
```

I'm hoping for something native like:

```
string name, desc, date;
string.ParseFormat("{0:4}{1:5}{2:4}", "bsarbirthd0692", out name, out desc, out date);
```

Is there a native way to do this in .NET or a popular library?

Comment: Fairly trivial to implement yourself? Its just wrapping substring calls after all ...

Comment: You can just use substring to do this since the format is fixed length.  You could also use regular expressions too - but that seems unnecessary since the format is fixed width.

Comment: Why not JSON? or XML?

Comment: Upvote for the suggestion of an inverse function to `string.Format`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since a format is known, and shouldn't change Substring should work for you

```
string data = "bsarbirthd0692";
string name, desc, date;
name = data.Substring(0, 4);
desc = data.Substring(4, 6);
date = data.SubString(10);
```

**EDIT**

There's also extension methods you can create to do what ever you want.  This is obviously more complex than previous suggestion

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string array of the original string broken apart by the parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">The original string</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Integer array of how long each broken piece will be</param>
    /// <returns>A string array of the original string broken apart</returns>
    public static string[] ParseFormat(this string str, params int[] obj)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        string[] pieces = new string[obj.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
        {
            if (startIndex + obj[i] < str.Length)
            {
                pieces[i] = str.Substring(startIndex, obj[i]);
                startIndex += obj[i];
            }
            else if (startIndex + obj[i] >= str.Length && startIndex < str.Length)
            {
                // Parse the remaining characters of the string
                pieces[i] = str.Substring(startIndex);
                startIndex += str.Length + startIndex;
            }

            // Remaining indexes, in pieces if they're are any, will be null
        }

        return pieces;
    }
}
```

Usage 1:

```
string d = "bsarbirthd0692";
string[] pieces = d.ParseFormat(4,6,4);
```

Result:

[image]

Usage 2:

```
string d = "bsarbirthd0692";
string[] pieces = d.ParseFormat(4,6,4,1,2,3);
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted: keeps the code simple and easy to understand.

Comment: _"format is known, and shouldn't change"_ even if a format is known it could change. For example if the data is not under your control. But it's easy to add a  `Length`-check before you use it.

Answer (score 16):

You can use Regexp for this

```
string str= "bsarbirthd0692";
var regex = "(?<name>.{4})(?<desc>.{6})(?<date>.{4})";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, regex);
foreach(Match m in matches){
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["desc"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["date"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Regular Expression is the solution I immediately thought of.  Almost exactly matches the desired semantics for the OP.

Comment: @mellamokb Regular expressions are a great hammer. Just make sure you're only using them on nails :D

Comment: A regex is overkill here (and the OP is obviously a regex virgin and doesn't need the extra confusion).  However, props for using named groups to avoid complete incomprehensibility for the newbie.

Comment: Unless the Regex is compiled, it'll be slower than simple substring calls. And when it is compiled, it might end up being "calls" to substring

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller I've used Regex plenty.  My question wasn't how do I solve the problem, but if there was a native .NET function or popular library that had already done it before creating my own implementation

Comment: @SarahBourt Perhaps I don't understand the original question.  If you know regular expressions, why wouldn't you use them for such a trivial problem?  How could there be any native library that is any simpler unless someone else has already encountered the _exact_ file format you are trying to parse (unlikely)?

Comment: @Luaan As my colleague once told me, "Phrase "Don't use hammer to drive screws in" doesn't mean you can instead use a wrench to slam them in."

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller The question was if .NET provided a native string function that would split a string into multiple bits based on a provided formatting string.  Presumably a native function would have had more optimization put into it.  Again the question wasn't "How do I solve this problem"--regex, substring looping, and plenty of other ways to do that.  It was if such a function that worked on a formatting string was already in existence in .NET.

Comment: @SarahBourt Don't go there. It hardly ever makes sense to care about performance until you actually have a performance problem (that is, keep performance in mind, but prefer readability when performance isn't paramount). And regular expressions are actually a pretty efficient way of handling strings, if you know what you're doing (after all, they're pretty well designed parsers). The assumption that native is faster is a dangerous one - and it ignores other costs involved. As long as you can always improve performance when needed, just ignore the perceived "inefficiency".

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing like that, however writing something to implement:

```
IEnumerable<string> inputString.BreakIntoLengths(4, 6, 4)
```

with signature:

```
public IEnumerable<string> BreakIntoLengths(this string input, params int[] lengths);
```

is very easy:

```
public IEnumerable<string> BreakIntoLengths(this string input, params int[] lengths) {

  var pos = 0;
  foreach (var len in lengths) {
    yield return input.Substring(pos, len);
    pos += len;
  }
}
```

(With a real implementation having some error checking.)

NB. I've dropped the format string like interface: it appears to offer no value. Once the collection is returned it is easy to assign entries by index.

Comment: How does yield work if I was calling this function?  A little embarassed to say I've never seen that keyword in action

Comment: @SarahBourt It makes it lazy. When `input` is long, or there are many lengths listed being eager generates many strings. Being lazy only those used by the caller will be generated.

Answer (score 2):

Better from what? Something like this?

```
var listStrings = new List<string>();
var tempIndex = 0;
var indexList = new List<int>{4, 6, 4}
foreach(var length in indexList)
{
    listStrings.Add(string.Substring(tempIndex , length);
    tempIndex += length 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no built-in way. I would use string methods like `Substring`:

```
string name, desc, date;
if (input.Length >= 4)
{
    name = input.Substring(0, 4);
    if (input.Length >= 10)
    {
        desc = input.Substring(4, 6);
        if (input.Length >= 14)
        {
            date = input.Substring(10, 4);
        }
    }
}
```